# What does below Sed Command Does?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a SED Command in a code and I need to understand what its actually doing ?

Below is what I see in code ?

```
show partitions {curr_table}' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > /tuber/dag_run_ctx/tbl_qc.csv;
```

Any idea what would the above Sed command do?

Comment: replaces tabs with commas. It's not  a great idea unless you know that your data does not contain commas.

Comment: It may depend on your sed version as `\t` is already a literal tab so `[\t]` MAY be still a literal tab or it may be the set of characters ```\``` and `t`. In any case if you want to translate tabs to commas use `tr $'\t' ','` as that's what `tr` exists to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace or substitute each occurrence of `<TAB>` character represented as `\t` with `,` character.

And save the output into file: `/tuber/dag_run_ctx/tbl_qc.csv`